# pthread_mutex_init failed while using qemu aarch-64

Tags: debugging, pthreads, embedded-linux, qemu, arm64

I tried to emulate aarch64 binary using qemu , I copy all the libraries that this binary depend on. and run it with chroot :

```
chroot . ./qemu-aarch64-static ./myProcess
```

The problem is that I see in log that `pthread_mutex_init` (implement in so file ) failed

How can I check why `pthread_mutex_init` failed? can I see the errno?

I have tried to debug that process ` maybe to see the return value of that function but it doesn't work.

Using `chroot . ./qemu-aarch64-static -g 1234 ./myProcess`

then connect with gdb-multiarch

```
file myProcess
set architecture aarch64
target remote 127.0.0.1:1234
b main
c
```

But the process doesn't stop at main

So I don't know why `pthread_mutex_init` failed and why I can't debug that process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I check why `pthread_mutex_init` failed? can I see the errno?

The pthreads functions are among those that return an error number on failure rather than setting the `errno` variable.

As with any function call whose failure you cannot reasonably ignore, your program must check calls to `pthread_mutex_init` for failure.  The natural idiom is

```
    int result;

    // ...

    result = pthread_mutex_init(&my_mutex, NULL);  // assumes default mutex attributes
    if (result != 0) {
        // ... handle error ...
    }
```

That idiom is already sufficient for easily seeing the error number via a debugger, at least a native debugger. I'm not sure I can explain the behavior you report for `gdb-multiarch`, but I suspect that the issue is that you're connecting after the program has started, but trying to break at (entry into) `main`.

The question remains, though, how do you actually handle the error.  In some cases, you might want to print a diagnostic message.  The `perror()` function is reasonably good for this, but it uses `errno` to determine what message to emit, so maybe ...

```
        errno = result;
        perror("pthread_mutex_init");
```

Messaging alone is rarely sufficient, however.  In most cases you will want to follow that up with terminating the program or aborting the function with a failure code.

Note also that for robustness and predictability, a program typically needs to do a lot of error checks along those lines.  You may find it makes your code cleaner and clearer to provide one or more macros and / or functions to replace all the boilerplate error handling.

Comment: That binary I research so I can't recompile that , I tried to debug it the watch the return value of `pthread_mutex_init` , do you have any idea? I didn't understand you solution .  I don't find any why to watch `errno`

Comment: @python3.789, again, `pthread_mutex_init` does not set `errno`. It *returns* an error number.  If the program is not capturing that in a variable then it may be tricky to observe it.

Comment: @python3.789, as for gdb, you are connecting to an already-running program and setting a breakpoint on function `main`.  But function breakpoints break on *entry* to the designated function, and by the time you connect, `main` will already have been entered.  That's likely why the debugged program does not stop again after you continue it.  So set your breakpoint somewhere else -- perhaps even on `pthread_mutex_init` -- and / or step through the program starting wherever it is when you connect.  You may also find it useful to generate backtraces to gather information about the call tree.